# String to date in impala

Tags: string, impala

I'm using SQL in Impala to write this query. I'm trying to put a where condition using a date stored like 2022-05-31 22:59:36. Below is my query

```
select  a.*, b.*
from impala.table a
left join impala.teableb b
    on a.key = b.key
where to_date(b.response_date) between date_trunc('month',  now()) - interval 1 month AND date_trunc('day',  now()) - interval 1 day
```

I am getting an error of AnalysisException:

> No matching function with signature: to_date(VARCHAR(26)). How can this be corrected?

Comment: Um, by reading the documentation for Impala and finding the function you need? Also please untag SQL Server since you apparently are not using SQL Server.

Comment: [Impala Type Conversion Functions - Cast](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/asf-site-html/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html#conversion_functions__cast)